# Adam's logic: Problem understanding a probability theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, logic

On Stanford's Encyclopedia of Philosophy, on the entry on [Logic and Probability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-probability/#CombLogiProbTheo), section $2.2$, some principles of Adam's logic are defined. On the very beginning of the section, we are told one can easily show' that the probability of a conclusion is the sum of the probabilities of its premises minus one. For example, the probability of a conclusion $q$ with premises $p\vee q$ and $p\to q$ is

$P(q) = P(p\vee q) + P(p\to q) - 1.$

However, this makes no sense to me for two reasons. Firstly, all probabilities are axiomatically constrained to $[0, 1]$. However, if the sum of the probability of each premise is less than $1$, then $P(q)$ would be negative, which makes no sense.

Secondly, it can also be the case that the probabilities add up exactly to 1 (for example, if both premises had a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$). In such a case, $P(q) = 0$, which also doesn't' make sense: both premises would be quite probable, why would that mean the conclusion is necessarily false?

Comment: "*However, if the sum of the probability of each premise is less than 1*"  Why do you believe this to be possible?  Recall that $p\to q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg p \vee q$

Comment: If it makes you feel better, rewrite your probabilities using disjoint sums of more elementary events; $(P(p)+P(\neg p \wedge q)) + (P(\neg p) + P(p\wedge q)) - 1$, note that $P(p)+P(\neg p) = 1$ and that $P(\neg p\wedge q)+P(p\wedge q) = P(q)$

Comment: @ryang I apologize for the delay, I have been very busy and, though I saw your reply, I couldn't make time to read it properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, the probability of a conclusion $q$ with premises $p\vee q$ and $p\to q$ is $P(q) = P(p\vee q) + P(p\to q) - 1.$

Noting that $P(a∨b)=P(a)+P(b)-P(a∧b),$
$$P(p∨q) + P(p\to q) - 1
\\=P(p∨q) + P(¬p∨q) - 1
\\=P\Big((p∨q) ∨ (¬p∨q)\Big)+P\Big((p∨q) ∧ (¬p∨q)\Big)- 1
\\=P\Big(\top\Big)+P\Big((p∧¬p) ∨ (p∧q) ∨ (q∧¬p) ∨ (q∧q)\Big)- 1
\\=P\Big((p∧¬p) ∨ (p∧q) ∨ (q∧¬p) ∨ (q∧q)\Big)
\\=P\Big( (p∧¬p) ∨ \big(q∧(p∨¬p)\big) ∨ (q∧q) )\Big)
\\=P\Big( \bot ∨ q ∨ q \Big)
\\=P(q).$$

> However, if the sum of the probability of each premise is less than $1$, then $P(q)$ would be negative, which makes no sense.

Suppose the former is $0.9;$ then $P(q)=0.9+0.9-1=0.8\not<0.$

> On the very beginning of the section, we are told one can easily show' that the probability of a conclusion is the sum of the probabilities of its premises minus one.

That particular sentence in the article is phrased a tad misleadingly: it actually means to refer *specifically* to the above example.

> Secondly, it can also be the case that the probabilities add up exactly to 1 (for example, if both premises had a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$). In such a case, $P(q) = 0$, which also doesn't' make sense

Those two premises $(p∨q)$ and $(¬p∨q)$ are not independent of each other; the sum of their probabilities exceed $1$ precisely because the *atomic* formula $q$ is not a contradiction.

Comment: I thank you sincerely. This made things clear to me :)